# initWithBarButtonItem change from UIBarButtonSystemItemPause to UIBarButtonSystemItemPlay?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibarbuttonitem

My application has a `UIBarButtonItem` with a `UIBarButtonItemPause` icon in the upper right corner of the screen on a `UINavigationBar`. I'm looking to have it so that when I press the button it changes the icon to a play button, and back to a pause button when it is unpaused (similar to the way in which iTunes, Quicktime, or iPhone's integrated media player does when pressing the play/pause button. Is it possible for me to just change the icon or would it be necessary to create a new button each time and place it on the bar for that to happen? The code that is triggered by the pressing of the button can be found here:

```
- (IBAction)pauseapp:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{
 if(paused==TRUE)
 {
  paused=FALSE;
  [pause initWithBarButtonSystemItem:(UIBarButtonSystemItemPause) target:self action:NULL];
  return;
 }
 else if(paused==FALSE)
 {
  paused=TRUE;
  [pause initWithBarButtonSystemItem:(UIBarButtonSystemItemPlay) target:self action:NULL];
  return;
 }
```

Comment: It seems like such an obvious thing to want to do and very strange that apple doens't let you change the SystemItem after you create the button.

Comment: Agreed. This API, like several others in iOS, was clearly designed by crackheads. I don't know what I'd do without S/O to help me route around all the idiocy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a new button each time; you should never call initXXX on an object more than one time (right after alloc).